# How to escape special characters in Groovy's SimpleTemplateEngine?

Tags: groovy, templates, escaping

By default, groovy's SimpleTemplateEngine uses `<% %>` as the scriptlet container. How do I escape these characters if I want to print out `<% %>`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a bug

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-399

Answer (score 0):

The book I've red (which might be outdated) says that you need to have variable that contains <% and %> and then you need to output those variables.